# What parts of the D3.js API are required for strictly animation (i.e. no charts, no plots, no diagrams, etc.)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm lost in the jungle of the D3.js API. Can someone pinpoint me to the parts of the API that I need to study in order to create animations of 2d sprites? Literally every book and tutorial that I came across deal only with charts, plots and diagrams and binding data to DOM elements. Surely there are other ways to use D3js. Actually at the bottom of Mike Bostock's gallery there are a limited number of examples which showcase D3js in fun ways (far from the world of data viz) however there is scant documentation on this, if any at all, merely a few examples.

https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/tadpoles

Comment: Whoever gave a thumbs down should explain, it's very relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`d3-transition`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) should be all what you need.

It includes the following [dependencies](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/v1.3.2/package.json#L37):

- `d3-selection`, to select and manipulate DOM nodes
- `d3-interpolate` and `d3-ease`, to control the animation state
- `d3-timer` for the timing and flow management.

Besides `d3-transition`, [`d3-scale`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) might also be useful, depending on your use case.